# why !important doesn't work in css?

Tags: html, css

i want to zoom in all the font-size to 200% in my web, [here are some test code in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karlsong/eom40w0L/7/),

if really PX issue, but why here the code are working if i add the style in "<-h2>" ?

```
<div  >
<h2 class="test" style="font-size:300% !important">
hello
</h2>
<h2 class="test2">
hello
</h2>
<h2 class="test3">
hello
</h2>
```

or, there is another question how can i enlarge all the font-size on a same rate?

Comment: Start using "rem" units.

Comment: It's because you have add specific css for all h2 tag.. if you add any content in without any tag it working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use em and rem.

You can use this http://pxtoem.com/

HTML

```
<div style="font-size:2rem !important" >
    <h2 class="test">
    hello
    </h2>
    <h2 class="test2">
    hello
    </h2>
    <h2 class="test3">
    hello
    </h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.test{
  font-size:1em;
}
.test2{
  font-size:2em;
}
.test3{
  font-size:3em;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eom40w0L/8/

Comment: @kernallora Maybe, it is because the parent won't affect the children. Rem and em are from css3.

Comment: please get my update in my question, if it's px issue, but why here the code are working if i add the style in "<-h2>" ?

Comment: It's because you add it to the h2 which is the child of div that has the font-size attribute. This is the only way to manipulate font-size in css. Or maybe you can find js library. There's alot out there.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is not working because you have used PX

you can use  relative units for that

[click here for absolute and relative units](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.test{
  font-size:10px;
}
.test2{
  font-size:20px;
}
.test3{
  font-size:30px;
}

div h2{
  zoom:300%!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="data">


<h2 class="test">
hello
</h2>
<h2 class="test2">
hello
</h2>
<h2 class="test3">
hello</h2>

</div>
```

you can also use Zoom property like this

```css
.test{
  font-size:10px;
}
.test2{
  font-size:20px;
}
.test3{
  font-size:30px;
}

.data{
  zoom:300%!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="data">


<h2 class="test">
hello
</h2>
<h2 class="test2">
hello
</h2>
<h2 class="test3">
hello</h2>

</div>
```

Comment: it's cool , but this will zoom the whole web, now i just want to enlarge the font in my web, any other workaround?

Comment: im not sure but....im adding another answer with a minor change...i think this will help you...instead of not reaching ur expectation im sorry..